# how to replace GTileLayer in google maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, tiles, google-maps-api, tile-map-service

I need to port code of one application written in Google Mapa API v.2 to API v.3. There is several layers taken via TMS, that are displayed using GTileLayer class. It is as simple as:

```
var tilelayer_tematyczne = new GTileLayer(null, null, null, {
    tileUrlTemplate: 'http://domain/geoserver/gwc/service/gmaps?layers=layer&zoom={Z}&x={X}&y={Y}&format=image/png',
    isPng:true,
    opacity:1 
});

tilesTematyczne = new GTileLayerOverlay(tilelayer_tematyczne);
map.addOverlay(tilesTematyczne);
```

I do not see any similar class in API v3. How do you cope with that problem? How to display TMS on top of Google Maps?

Comment: Is this question of any use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915944/replacing-gtilelayer-in-google-maps-v3-with-imagemaptype-tile-bounding-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brief google search has lead me to [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-maps-api@googlegroups.com/msg53257.html) page which says:

> ...in the API V3, with the MapType object, you write your own
>   .getTile() method:
>   http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MapType
>
> Sample: http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_customTiles.html

Further Research has lead me to [this feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1422) on Google Code. According to the attached Change Log,there is a New ImageMapType object to support custom map tiles

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#ImageMapType

Answer (score 0):

Another Example:
Mapserver is used as the service creating the tiles/vectors

Using http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arcgislink/examples/simpleags.html

Code:
http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arcgislink/examples/simpleags.js

(I think this was created as a workaround for the same issue)